# Arrows do not appear in graphdrawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-graphs

I try to draw a diagram showing how different areas communicate with each other. In the end it should have the areas labelled `A1,...,A5` in a circle and there will be many labelled arrows between them. The code in the minimal working example below produces the correct style and the labels appear as I want them to but the arrows do not. Why not? Where has the arrow between `A1` and `A4` gone?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphs,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\tikzset{
  every picture/.style={simple necklace layout, node distance=78pt},  
  new set=areas,
  area/.style n args={1}{set=areas, draw, circle,inner sep=1pt,node contents={A#1}},
  every edge/.style={rounded corners,nodes={font=\scriptsize,sloped}}
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,...,5} \node (A\i) [area={\i}] {};

\graph{
(areas);
A1 ->["communicate new standards"] A4
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am looking for a solution which will allow me to keep the tikzset commands outside of the tikzpicture and/or graph environment as there will be many pictures with the same style in the final document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value of the `every edge` style is simply `draw`. In your redefinition of the style you've left out `draw`, so the path isn't actually drawn. Either add `draw` back in to the style, or use `every edge/.append style` instead of `every edge/.style`. With `append style` your options are added to the existing definition, rather than replacing it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphs,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\tikzset{
  every picture/.style={simple necklace layout, node distance=78pt},  
  new set=areas,
  area/.style n args={1}{set=areas, draw, circle,inner sep=1pt,node contents={A#1}},
  %%% use append style here,
  every edge/.append style={rounded corners, nodes={font=\scriptsize,sloped}}
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,...,5} \node (A\i) [area={\i}] {};

\graph{
(areas);
A1 ->["communicate new standards"] A4
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not `.append style`?

Comment: @egreg Good point. No real reason, I guess the first thing that came to mind was to add `draw`. I'll edit :)